# Postgres if condition comparing timestamps in trigger not working

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to implement soft delete with triggers. So that when a record in a table is soft deleted, a trigger handles soft deleting all dependent rows in another table. That is, table B has a foreign key to table A. When I soft delete a record in table A, I want all records in table B with a foreign key to the affected record in table A to also get soft deleted.

The main implementation of the trigger works. But I want to make sure that I don't update any records unless I actually need to. So if a soft deleted record in table A would be updated again for some reason, the records in table B should not be updated.

This is the first implementation that works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TableB_SoftDelete_WhenTableASoftDeleted() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'OLD.deleted_at: %', OLD.deleted_at;
        RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.deleted_at: %', NEW.deleted_at;
        IF NEW.deleted_at IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Will update Table B with a_id %', NEW.id;
            UPDATE table_b
                SET deleted_at = NEW.deleted_at
                WHERE a_id = NEW.id;
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'IF didnt match...';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TableA_AU AFTER UPDATE ON table_a
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TableB_SoftDelete_WhenTableASoftDeleted();
```

So when I do `UPDATE table_a SET deleted_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = 1;` I get the following log:

```
NOTICE:  OLD.deleted_at: <NULL>
NOTICE:  NEW.deleted_at: 2023-02-07 07:51:15.869723
NOTICE:  Will update Table B with a_id 1
```

But this would obviously update Table B any time an already soft deleted record in Table A is updated again.
So then I try to change my condition into `IF NEW.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND NEW.deleted_at != OLD.deleted_at THEN`, but then my IF isn't hit anymore, and I don't understand why.
I see this in the log:

```
NOTICE:  OLD.deleted_at: <NULL>
NOTICE:  NEW.deleted_at: 2023-02-07 07:52:31.22866
NOTICE:  IF didnt match...
```

`deleted_at` is differing in the OLD and NEW records.
`deleted_at` in both tables are of the type `timestamp(6) without time zone`.

Comment: You can just make your trigger: `UPDATE table_b SET deleted_at = coalesce(NEW.deleted_at, table_b.deleted_at) WHERE a_id = NEW.id;` - ie with no `IF`

Comment: @Bohemian Won't that result in the records in table B being updated even if `deleted_at` wasn't changed in table A?

Comment: @Bohemian I just confirmed that the row is in fact updated with your suggested solution. So according to my specifications, it's not a valid solution.

Comment: You can restrict when the trigger fires with something along the lines of `WHEN (OLD.deleted_at IS NULL)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many databases, logical operations work like this:

```
null != '2023-02-07' Returns = false
```

So it's better if you write like this:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'OLD.deleted_at: %', OLD.deleted_at;
RAISE NOTICE 'NEW.deleted_at: %', NEW.deleted_at;
IF ((OLD.deleted_at is null) and (NEW.deleted_at IS NOT null)) or (OLD.deleted_at != NEW.deleted_at) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Will update Table B with a_id %', NEW.id;
    UPDATE table_b
        SET deleted_at = NEW.deleted_at
        WHERE a_id = NEW.id;
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'IF didnt match...';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. The condition is fairly hard to read for me though, so I don't quite like it. But with your initial bit of information about how comparing with nulls work, I googled and found another syntax. `IS DISTINCT FROM`. So the whole IF then becomes `IF NEW.deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND NEW.deleted_at IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.deleted_at THEN`. That also works, and reads better to me. But your answer fulfills all my specified requirements, and you pointed me in the right direction, so I'll accept it!